# Programmatically convert video files from WMV to MPEG in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, converters, mpeg, wmv

How to convert unprotected WMV ([Windows Media Video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Video)) files to [MPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_Picture_Experts_Group) (or [H.264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC)) format within my native (Swift/Objective-C) Mac app?

I want my Mac server to make WMV content available to [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) or [tvOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) client apps in a format supported by the iOS/tvOS video playback libraries.

Comment: Have you looked at ffmpeg?

Comment: @JosephYoung No, I've not. Sounds like that might make a good Answer.